# can't create server-admin in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I'm following the couchdb security documentation (http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/intro/security.html) to try to create a server-admin using cURL: curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/admins/anna -d '"secret"'

When I do this, I get an error:
{"error":"not_found","reason":"Database does not exist."}

I'm on v2.0 so I don't known if something has changed since the 1.6 version of the documentation.  I can create server-admins just fine using fauxton. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18):

To anybody else running into this issue, it's an easy answer: in couchdb 2.0 some of the APIs moved to using port 5986 ... I had been using port 5984 (which is still used a lot in v2.0, but apparently not for the _config endpoint).

The following works:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5986/_config/admins/admin1 -d '"password"'
```

Comment: Does anyone know where this is documented? I had the exact same issue. I'm fairly sure it was working on port 5984 to begin with, then a some point it changed to 5986

Comment: Apparently the docs are not quite caught up in CouchDB 2. We should indeed use /_node/nodename/_config (I'm reliably informed this is because CouchDB 2 can work in a cluster). The other advice I was given was to check the /_membership interface (on port 5984) for a list of nodes

Answer (score 6):

The Couchdb2 way of adding a user is

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/_node/nodename/_config/admins/admin1 -d '"password"'
```

Comment: I've just heard back from the CouchDB community. Yes, the 5986 port will be deprecated. The docs will be presumably be updated as well to reflect the new API.

Comment: This solution works when you have CouchDB as a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

In the GUI, you can find out that you need to set up a single node cluster, and when you do that you specify the admin username and password.

And you can do the same thing using an API endpoint that you can POST to:
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/server/common.html#post--_cluster_setup

With 2.0 using `enable_single_node` returned `{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Invalid Action'"}` so I reverted to doing:

```
j=$(cat <<EOF
{
  "action": "enable_cluster",
  "bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "$PASS",
  "port": "5984",
  "node_count":"1"
} 
EOF
)

curl  -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://$IP/_cluster_setup -d "$j"
curl  -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" $URI/_cluster_setup -d '{"action": "finish_cluster"}'
```